# Aurelia transpiler: "this" is "null"

Tags: aurelia

I have the following code in my Aurelia app:

```
import {digit} from "../util/random" // generates a random digit [0,9]

export class UnitedStates {

  zipCode() {
    return ""+digit(5);
  };

  zipPlus4() {
    return this.zipCode()+"-"+digit(4);
  };

  ...

}
```

Getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'zipCode' of null` on the body of `zipPlus4`. Inspection in the developer tool reveals that `this` is `null`.

Why is `this` `null`, and how do I fix this?

Comment: How do you call `zipPlus4` method?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the transpiler. Recall that the arrow function notation maintains lexical `this` (or [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more). So, when Babel and other transpilers enter a new scope, they maintain a local this variable so that it will be accessible from any child scopes. Usually, this variable is `_this`.

Sometimes, debuggers like DevTools have a hard time understanding the sourcemaps, and they report a null `this`. Turns out, this is only when inspecting the code; when running the code, it works properly.

So how do you inspect the value of `this` when it is reported to be null? Inspect `_this`, usually from the console. That will give you the true `this` value that is being used.

Comment: if this solved your issue, please be sure to upvote and accept for future users, thanks!